# Find all instances that inherit from base class

Tags: debugging, clr, windbg, sos

In WinDbg, I used *!name2ee* to find a baseclass's EEClass and MethodTable.
How can I find all instances that inherit from that specific type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wish there is an easy answer and someone else can solve it easier than this.

### Background information

1. dump all objects in a way you can get the addresses from the output: `!dumpheap -short`
2. loop over all those objects `.foreach ( adr {!dumpheap -short}) { ... }`
3. The method table will be the first pointer size bytes at the address of the object, so instead of `!do <address>` to find the method table, you can also do `? poi(<address>)`.

   `!dumpmt` does not list the base class, so you need to find it yourself. On 64 bit, the base class is 16 bytes away, so to get the type of a base class from an object address, you can do `!dumpmt poi(poi(<address>)+0x10)`. You can repeat that to get the base-base class: `!dumpmt poi(poi(<address>)+0x10)+0x10)`.

   You can repeat this until the pointer is 0x00000000, which means you have reached *System.Object* and there is no more base class.

   Since you want to automate this process, you need to put that into a loop as well:

   `r$t0 =poi(<address>); 
   .while(@$t0) { .if(@$t0 == <basemt>) {...}; r$t0=poi(@$t0+0x10);}`
4. Do whatever you want with the address, e.g. just list it: `.echo ${adr}` or dump it: `!do ${adr}`.
5. Put it all together.

### Example

Since I don't know what you're looking for, I'll use `Exception` as an example. And since there's always a `StackOverflowException`, `OutOfMemoryException` and `ExecutionEngineException` in any .NET program, it should at least find three objects if you try it.

```
0:021> !name2ee *!System.Exception
Module:      000007fef2091000
Assembly:    mscorlib.dll
Token:       0000000002000005
MethodTable: 000007fef2776738
EEClass:     000007fef214d7b0
Name:        System.Exception
```

So the `<basemt>` parameter which I'm looking for is `000007fef2776738`.

The full statement is now (formatted for readability):

```
.foreach ( adr {!dumpheap -short}) { 
    r$t0 =poi(${adr}); 
    .while(@$t0) { 
        .if(@$t0 == 000007fef2776738) {!do ${adr}}; 
        r$t0=poi(@$t0+0x10);
    }
}
```

or (formatted for copy & paste):

```
.foreach ( adr {!dumpheap -short}) { r$t0 =poi(${adr}); .while(@$t0) { .if(@$t0 == 000007fef2776738) {!do ${adr}}; r$t0=poi(@$t0+0x10);} }
```